# How to call useRouter inside useFetch's onFetchError by VueUse?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, composable, vueuse

I need to create a custom fetch composable from VueUse using createFetch() and I want to check if a request returns 401 status, I'd like the route to be redirected to the login route.

```js
export const useApiFetch = createFetch({
  baseUrl: import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL,
  options: {
    beforeFetch({ options }) {
      const { user } = useSessionStore()
      if (user)
        options.headers.Authorization = `Basic ${user.user_id}:${user.password}`
      return { options }
    },
    onFetchError(response) {
      const route = useRoute()
      const router = useRouter()
      if (route.name !== 'login' && response.status === 401)
        return router.push('/login')
    }
  }
})
```

But everytime it hits the error, useRoute and useRouter are undefined, and yes.. I have checked that it runs in setup

```js
<script setup>
const submit = async () => {
  const { error, data } = await useApiFetch('/login').post(form)
}
</script>
```

Did I miss something or is there a better way to do this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Vue composables are primarily expected to be called in setup block. Other usages depend on their implementation and needs to be confirmed. The main restriction is that a composable is linked to specific component instance, in this case `useRouter` uses `provide`/`inject` to get router instance through component hierarchy; this often can be be deduced without checking the actual implementation.

It's possible to directly import router instance instead of using `useRouter` but this may result in module circular dependencies and this may not be work for other composables.

`createFetch` wasn't designed for this usage and needs to be wrapped with custom composable that guarantees that other composables will be called in time:

```
let useApiFetchFn;

const useApiFetch = (...args) => {
  if (!useApiFetchFn) {
    const sessionStore = useSessionStore()
    const route = useRoute()
    const router = useRouter()

    useApiFetchFn = createFetch(...)
  }

  return useApiFetchFn(...args);
}
```

Whether it's correct to cache the result to `useApiFetchFn` depends on the implementation, in this case it's acceptable. At this point it may be more straightforward to use `useFetch` directly and compose the options similarly to how [`createFetch` does that](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/main/packages/core/useFetch/index.ts#L250-L305), most of its code is dedicated to TS support and variadic arguments that may not be needed in this case.